# How to change AWS Lambda content type from Plain text to html

Tags: node.js

I want to display on my chatbot the link.

```
message: { contentType: 'PlainText', content:"<a href="www.google.com">Test Result</a>" },
```

html tag displays as it is. How can I display the content as html?

Answer (score 37):

You need to set the `content-type` to `text/html` in the `headers` of your response object, as typically it is (implicitly) set to `application/json`.

Projected to your case, you need to return your function in your AWS Lambda handler like:

```
callback(null, {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {"content-type": "text/html"},
  body: "<html><body>OK</body></html>"
})
```

That will set the content type correctly for the client to parse.

Comment: +1. Apparently, header fields are *CASE SENSITIVE*. i.e. `Content-Type`, won't work while `content-type` will.

Comment: According to the HTTP standard, field names are case-insensitive, https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html. It might be that AWS Lambda or AWS API Gateway does interpret the `headers` hash differently though.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about headers, and I also think the same about AWS specific case.

Answer (score 10):

For those that are using the serverless framework, you can configure the content-type of your function's response in your serverless.yml file, for example:

```
  downloadImage:
    handler: lib/client-app-services.downloadImage
    events:
     - http:
        path: client/images/{filename}
        method: get
        cors: true
        integration: lambda
        response:
          headers:
            Content-Type: "'image/jpeg'"
            Cache-Control: "'max-age=120'"
```

Comment: Is there any reason for using double quotes around the single quotes? `"'image/jpeg'"`